# select rows which satisfy where clause AND rows which share a common key

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select rows which satisfy my where clause AND rows that share a common field. In this example I want to get both child rows, but I always get the first child joined to the second, rather than a single row for each child containing only that child's data.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(10) not null
  );

CREATE TABLE child (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(10) not null,
  parent_id int not null,
  foreign key (parent_id) references parent(id)
  );

INSERT INTO parent (id, name) VALUES (1, 'mom');

INSERT INTO child (id, name, parent_id) VALUES (1, 'hal', 1), (2, 'boe', 1);

SELECT * FROM child c1 JOIN child c2 ON c1.parent_id = c2.parent_id WHERE c1.name = 'hal'
```

Gives me the results

```
id  name    parent_id   id  name    parent_id
1   hal          1       1  hal       1
1   hal          1       2  boe       1
```

When really I want

```
id  name    parent_id
1   hal       1
2   boe       1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95615a/6

Comment: Just change your query to `SELECT c2.* FROM...`. Keep in mind it's almost always better to list out the columns you want instead of using `*`.

Comment: Could you give an example Little elaborate? From the output you have mentioned as example there is no clear picture of what you're trying to achieve with the sample data.

Comment: So what result you want? All children from a parent? Hal and all his brothers/sister?

Answer (score 2):

This return all `'hal'` siblings and also return `'hal'`

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95615a/23)**

```
SELECT *
FROM child c1
WHERE c1.parent_id = (SELECT c2.parent_id
                      FROM child c2
                      WHERE c2.name = 'hal');
```